# Google Calendar API, getItem and getSummery returns nothing

Tags: php, api, google-calendar-api

I seem to have bumped into a google calendar api problem. and I can't really see where I have made the error so an extra set of eyes would be greatly appreciated. The problem in short is that the part of the code that should output the events.. doesn't (the "result" part of the code.

```
require_once "./google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php";
require_once "./google-api-php-client/src/Google/Service/Calendar.php";

// Service Account info
$client_id          = "XXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com";
$app_name               = "Some-name";
$service_account_name   = 'XXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
$key_file_location  = 'google-api-php-client/Some-name-xxxxxxxxxx.p12';
$cal_id             = "primary";

// Service Account info
$client_id              = $client_id;
$service_account_name   = $service_account_name;
$key_file_location  = $key_file_location;

// Calendar id
$calName                = $cal_id;


$client = new Google_Client();
$client -> setApplicationName($app_name);

$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);

$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $service_account_name,
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'),
    $key
);

$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);

$cals = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();
print_r($cals);
echo "<br>events<br>";

$events = $service->events->listEvents($calName);

var_dump($events);

echo "<br>result:<br>";
// the following is what returns nothing, works fine until this point.

$i = 0;
foreach ( $events->getItems() as $event ) {
    echo 'i:'.$i.' '.$event->getSummary();
    $i++;
}
echo 'end';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change $events to the below line:

$events = $service->events->listEvents('primary', $params);

Instead of primary, add $calName and also send $params in listEvents method.

Hope this works.

Comment: I wouldn't know to be honest because now it throws an 'Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "invalid_grant" }'

I wish the doicumentation wasn't such a mess of dated code/documentation.

Comment: Invalid_grant error is thrown when the refresh token is not working.This happens when number of refresh tokens exceeds the limit, older tokens become invalid. So, when application attempts to use invalid refresh token, invalid_grant error response is returned.